# Compojure-specific destructuring and query strings

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I'm trying to access the parameter *foo*, using compojure, in a request like this:

```
/api/xyz?foo=bar
```

The [compojure destructuring syntax](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Destructuring-Syntax) looks good, so I would like to use it. However the following just serves me the "Page not found":

```
(defroutes app-routes    
  (GET "/api/xyz/:foo" [foo] (str "foo: " foo))
  (route/not-found "Page not found"))
```

Which is kind of weird, since the verbose destructuring below works and gives me "foo: bar":

```
(defroutes app-routes    
  (GET "/api/xyz" {{foo :foo} :params} (str "foo: " foo))
  (route/not-found "Page not found"))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `foo` is always passed as a URL parameter, you want your code to be like this:

```
(defroutes app-routes    
  (GET "/api/xyz" [foo] (str "foo: " foo))
  (route/not-found "Page not found"))
```